# Django making querys inside template

Tags: python, django

I have the following problem. I need to get the information of the question based on the questionitem.question_id
I have the following files.

```
# models.py

class Question(models.Model):
    qtype_id = models.ForeignKey(QuestionType, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    q_discription = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.pk

class QuestionItem(models.Model):
    exam_id = models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_pontuation = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.pk


# views.py

def ExamDetail(request, exam_id):
    exam = get_object_or_404(Exam, pk=exam_id)
    questionitems = QuestionItem.objects.filter(exam_id= exam_id).values_list('id', flat=True)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(pk__in=questionitems)
    context = {
        'exam': exam,
        'questions': questions,
        'questionitem': questionitems,
    }
    return render(request, 'evaluation/exam_detail.html' , context)
```

And now on exam_detail.html i have something like this:

```
{% for questionitem in exam.questionitem_set.all %}
    Question {{questionitem.id}}</a>:  {{question.q_discription}}
{% endfor%}
```

but nothing shows, and i need to show the description of the question in questionitem.question_id, and i cant change the `models.py`.

Comment: Could you please share with us the `Exam` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you have problem in the way, you are accessing queryset in loop. Change code to :-

```
{% for questionitem in exam.questionitem_set.all %}
   Question {{questionitem.id}}</a>:  {{questionitem.question_id.q_discription}}
{% endfor%}
```

q_discription is the part of Question class, which is accessible using question_id on questionitem instance, that you receive in the loop.